# Transform an array of hashes to an array of nested hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I want to modify my array of hashes to facilitate better search performance

I have:

```
a = [ {"id" => 1, "name" => "Matt", "email" => "matt@example.com"}, {"id" => 2, "name" => "Charlie", "email" => "charlie@example.com"} ]
```

I want to transform this into:

```
b = [ {1 => { "name" => "Matt", "email" => "matt@example.com"}},{2 => { "name" => "Charlie", "email" => "charlie@example.com"}} ]
```

Note that the "id" field won't necessarily be a sequential or contiguous set, but each occurrence will be unique. Also, the hash nested as a value in b can contain 'id' key/value pair if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
a.map{|record| the_id = record.delete("id"); {the_id => record}}
```

Comment: This will create an array of 1-element hashes of hash-objects, not a hash of hash-objects as the OP wishes (i.e. it will just wrap each *individual* hash-object into its own private little hash).

Comment: This will modify the content of the original a array

Comment: @Amadan Matt does ask for an array of hashes… Although he is probably confused.

Answer (score 2):

To get the array you describe:

```
b = a.map {|i| { i["id"] => i } }
```

But note that if you are doing this to perform efficient searches by `id` then build a hash instead of an array:

```
b = a.inject({}) {|h,i| h[i["id"]]=i; h}
```

Comment: @Matt Did you make sure you ran this in a fresh Ruby? Amadan’s first answer as well as Nate Murray’s will trash your `a` array so that my answer does not work anymore.

Comment: My apologies, I did indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.each_with_object({}) { |x, h| h[x.delete('id')] = x }
```

This will construct a new hash (`{}`), pass it into the block as `h` with each element `x`. In the block `x.delete('id')` removes the `id` key/value from `x`, and returns it so it can be used as the index to assign a value to the resultant `h` hash.

EDIT per kmkaplan's comment: If you still need the original array, use this:

```
a.each_with_object({}) { |x, h| c = x.clone; h[c.delete('id')] = c }
```

EDIT per kmkaplan's other comment: If the OP really isn't confused, Nate Murray's answer is the right one.

Comment: This will modify the content of the original `a` array.